# In an OpenStack cluster, must all machines be of the same processor architecture?

Tags: openstack, processor

With OpenStack's architecture, is it possible to, for instance, have a PowerPC64 (Altivec) machine, a Intel CoreDuo machine, and a ARMv6 all on the same cluster?
Or is this impossible, because of the restrictions in building buildpacks when deploying to multiple architectures?

*EDIT: Whoops, I meant OpenStack, not OpenShift ;)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is correct (answer from developercorey).
Although whether this suits you depends on how its managed and what your trying to achieve. Typically when you add servers with different physical attributes such as CPU, Disk, Network cards etc you group them into different host aggregates.

By default when you launch a VM it will try and find a suitable host, but you can also tag it, so for example if your VM required alot of disk IO, you might want to place it on a host that has SSD drivers.  So you can put those hosts into a 'SSD' aggregate, and then when launching your VM you can make sure it goes to a host in that aggregate.

If your just trying to make the most out of the hardware you have, then I don't see any issue by mixing them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that they have to be, but I do believe that they only build packages for 1 or 2 architechtures, so I'm not sure how many options you really have there.

Comment: That seems about right, I'm not sure if buildpacks are in OpenStack, or in an external layer like CloudFoundry.